# Routing doesn't find controller with the same name as area

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I followed article about Areas in [ASP:NET MVC 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC) (section How to Avoid Name Conflict). I'm using MVC 5, but I suppose all the features from version 4 are available and should work in version 5.

My directory structure:

[image]

File EpicAreaRegistration.cs content:

```
namespace App1.Web.UI.Areas.Epic
{
  public class EpicAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
  {
    public override string AreaName
    {
      get{ return "Epic"; }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
      context.MapRouteLocalized(
         name: "Epic_default",
         url: "Epic/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Pm", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
         namespaces: new[] { "App1.Web.UI.Areas.Epic.Controllers" }
      );
    }
 }
```

}

My project's App_Start -> RouteConfig.cs file content: **UPDATE** corrected namespace

```
  public class RouteConfig
  {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
          namespaces: new[] { "App1.Web.UI.Controllers" } // according to article namespace must be added here, so ASP.NET router distinguishes between request: e
      );
    }
  }
```

And finally I have EpicController.cs file in project's directory Controllers:

```
namespace App1.Web.UI.Controllers
{
  public class EpicController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult Browse()
    {
      return View();
    }
  }
```

}

When I navigate to: http://localhost:7300/Epic/Pm it works (finds it), but http://localhost:7300/Epic/Browse doesn't work (404 - not found). What have I missed?

My assumption is that request goes through some kind of routing table. If it doesn't find Epic/Browse in Areas, it should move to project's root Controller folder. It's the same analogy as with Views (folder, if not in folder look in Shared, ...)

Additionally I registered all areas in Application_Start

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
  void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `Area` controller uses the correct namespace.

Namespace for EpicController is currently:

```
namespace App1.Web.UI.Controllers
```

Change it to:

```
namespace App1.Web.UI.Areas.Epic.Controllers
```

Comment: Zaki, thank you it was a typo when I posted namespace (I've hidden actual application name, therefore named it App1, but it still doesn't work). +1 for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is also Epic. So your URL would look like

http://localhost:7300/Epic/Epic/Browse

Comment: Areas are accesible the same way as controllers in project root, but with a prefix "area name". Epic/Epic would work if you would wrote custom Route Map/Rule.

Comment: His area is also defined in the route. That's why I suggested he hit the site that way. It's his only route so epic/controllername (also epic) is how he hits it.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to access,

```
http://localhost:7300/Areas/Epic/Epic/Browse
```

As It's contained in sub folder.